# Layout behind status bar - Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, transparent, statusbar

I want in my application to be able to implement this effect:
[image]

where the status bar is semi transparent and the layout is behind the status bar. Every example that I've read on the subject, was mainly associated with the navigation drawer and mostly used the ScrimInsetScrollView (or ScrimInsetsFrameLayout). I tried implementing this with ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.

Basically I have an activity that holds a fragment, and this is my layout (the fragment is later added to the container in the activity's onCreate method):

```
 <FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <com.test.app.widget.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        ></com.test.app.widget.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

     </FrameLayout>
```

And also I've set the android:statusBarColor to transparent in themes.
The solution does not work for me. Apparently I am doing something wrong here.
Can someone point out where I am mistaken?

Comment: Now, this effect can be easily accomplished by using the components from the new design support library (v23)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

as described in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)

Comment: No, but I am not using an action bar in my activity. I am using a toolbar, but in my incorporated fragment. I tried just now, since you suggested, and I am not getting the desired effect.